# How to access Amazon Keyspaces via shell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, nosql, amazon-keyspaces, wide-column-store

I tried writing `cqlsh` in the AWS shell, but it returned no output. I referred this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/getting-started.ddl.html)

output:- `bash: cqlsh: command not found`

Comment: Installation instructions are on: [Using cqlsh to connect to Amazon Keyspaces - Amazon Keyspaces (for Apache Cassandra)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/programmatic.cqlsh.html)

Comment: in the aws shell how can i access it?

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS Shell"? Do you mean the AWS CloudShell? The documentation says that `cqlsh` is installed as part of Cassandra, but you probably don't want to install that in the CloudShell.

Comment: Yes I can't access it in the cloudshell

Comment: `cqlsh` is part of Cassandra, but the CloudShell does not have Cassandra installed. I suspect that there might not be enough disk space to do a Cassandra installation there.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use cqlsh to access Amazon Keyspaces via the AWS Cloudshell.  The repository for the Amazon Keyspaces toolkit has a shell script to setup the cqlsh in the AWS cloud shell. The Amazon Keyspaces toolkit is a repository for commonly used developer tooling configured for best practices in Amazon Keyspaces.

Here is a link to the github example: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-toolkit/tree/master/aws-cloudshell

Below are the steps to help you get started.

Run the following commands to download and execute the setup script
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-toolkit/master/aws-cloudshell/setup.sh
bash setup.sh

By using the cqlsh-expansion it also allows you to utilize the Sigv4 Authentication method, this method supports the Python Cassandra driver. For more information  here is a Github page about our Sigv4 plug in and the Python driverhttps://github.com/aws/aws-sigv4-auth-cassandra-python-driver-plugin.

The plugin depends on the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3), uses boto3.Session to obtain credentials to connect to Amazon keyspaces  using cqlsh-expansion

```
cqlsh-expansion cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com 9142 --ssl --auth-provider "SigV4AuthProvider"
```

Additional info
cqlsh-expansion https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-toolkit/tree/master/cqlsh-expansion#readme
AWS CloudShell https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/welcome.html